# Matlab: 'struct/or table vs sqlite3' to save results + metadata

Tags: database, matlab, data-structures, struct, grouping

I am searching for an appropriate data structure to save my results in. After analysis of my files (>1000), **results+metadata** for each file should be saved into a **single structure / table / db**, that **allows for subsequent analysis of the results** based on metadata (i.e. compare different groups). The *results per file* comprise several single values & a vector (*resultType*). The *metadata per file* comprise *4 features*. As I wrote, the idea is to compare result-values based on certain metadata features.

**Current approach**: save to *struct*:

```
results=struct

% metadata
results.metadata=struct
results.metadata.metaval1='val'

% results-values
results.results=struct
results.results.resultsType1=val
```

filter *results* corresponding to certain metadata-group features ('val1'-'val4') to obtain the values for *resultsType1*:

```
idx = strcmp('val1',{results.metadata.metaval1}) & ...
      strcmp('val2',{results.metadata.metaval2}) & ...
      strcmp('val3',{results.metadata.metaval3}) & ... 
      strcmp('val4',{results.metadata.metaval4}) ;

group1_resultType1 = results(idx).resultType1;
```

I was wondering, whether there might be a better/easier approach using maybe a sqlit3-database or simply a table to get result-values for chose metadata-features?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this, I'd recommend [MATLAB Tables](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/tables.html). You can structure your data to be read into a table(s) which look like:

```
T =
  3×4 table
    Files            Results             Metadata_Date    Metadata_Bool
    _____    ________________________    _____________    _____________
    {'A'}    {[1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10]}     08-Dec-2022         true     
    {'B'}    {[1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10]}     07-Dec-2022         false    
    {'C'}    {[1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10]}     09-Dec-2022         true
```

You can then access the data by querying the table on row, column, or some combination of the two:

```
% Get entries that were uploaded before today
>> T(T.Metadata_Date < datetime('Today'),:)
ans =
  1×4 table
    Files            Results             Metadata_Date    Metadata_Bool
    _____    ________________________    _____________    _____________
    {'B'}    {[1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10]}     07-Dec-2022         false
```

If you store data in multiple tables, you can perform joins and set operations like you can in SQL.